# Duplicates results with left join in Sql database

Tags: sql

I'm facing some issues at the moment with an sql query for prestashop and have no idea of how to delete the duplicate results

This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ps_product.id_product
        , ps_product_lang.name
        , ps_category_lang.link_rewrite as categoryName
        , ps_product_lang.description_short
        , ps_product_lang.link_rewrite
        , ps_product.condition
        , available_now
        , ps_product.price
        , ps_product_lang.id_lang 
FROM ps_product 
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang ON ps_product.id_product = ps_product_lang.id_product
LEFT JOIN ps_category_lang ON ps_product.id_category_default = ps_category_lang.id_category
WHERE ps_product_lang.id_lang = 1;
```

the problem is that I'm getting duplicates rows and I only need one row 
per Id based on the language and this is the result I'm getting:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Wyxd-54fbsbjBwMHJFbEpRVHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Show us some data, current and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 and here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Please put the schema, actual and expected result so we can understand your query better.

Comment: It is because one or both joined tables may have multiple rows for the same product. Try narrowing the query by using a `where` clause maybe for the language you want the products to be.

Comment: If you try `SELECT *` you'll probably see some differences amongst the other columns. Then you can decide how to reduce your selection.

Comment: @jarlh i tried SELECT * but im getting more duplicates rows

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza
I edited the post in order to make simple.

Comment: I didn't say that was the answer, it's just a way to make the problem a bit clearer.

Comment: Point is that this rows are surely not same. I'm sure there is at least one difference in one of those columns: ps_product.id_product
        , ps_product_lang.name
        , ps_category_lang.link_rewrite as categoryName
        , ps_product_lang.description_short
        , ps_product_lang.link_rewrite
        , ps_product.condition
        , available_now
        , ps_product.price
        , ps_product_lang.id_lang

That's way DISTINCT not works. You need to find which columns make problems, and either remove those columns, or modify WHERE statements

Comment: In Your screen You can observe that categoryName has different values.

Comment: Do you get any null-results? A null is always considered a unique value, so if you have two seemingly equal rows with a  null-value, they are not considered equal from the DBMS point of view

Comment: Which rows do you consider equal? As far as I can see, all of the rows are unique. (for the two first, do not consider tshirts and t-shirts as equal)

Comment: If in Your category table exists id_lang, You should try to use it in where also: WHERE ps_product_lang.id_lang = 1 and ps_category_lang.id_lang = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting all category names for a category, no matter what language. So you get 'tshirts' plus 'tshirt' and 'blouses' plus 'chemisiers'. Add `AND ps_category_lang.id_lang = 1` to your query in order to only get the category names for that one language.

You are also using outer-joins here, so as to get products with missing language entries. But in an outer-joined record `ps_product_lang.id_lang` would be null. Your WHERE clause `WHERE ps_product_lang.id_lang = 1` will fail and discard every outer-joined record and you have what you would have got with a simlple INNER JOIN. Have conditions on outer-joined tables in the ON clause.

```
SELECT 
    p.id_product
  , p.name
  , cl.link_rewrite as categoryName
  , pl.description_short
  , pl.link_rewrite
  , p.condition
  , p.available_now
  , p.price
  , pl.id_lang 
FROM ps_product p
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON p.id_product = pl.id_product and pl.id_lang = 1
LEFT JOIN ps_category_lang cl ON p.id_category_default = cl.id_category and cl.id_lang = 1;
```